# Why do we save the Vue instance in a variable or a constant?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, instance

I am new to Vue. I have seen in most of the tutorials and documentation that the `new Vue` instance is being saved in an `app` or whatever named constant. I was wondering how does saving the Vue instance in a variable or a constant help?

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {},
  methods: {}
  // options
})
```

Comment: If you never use the `app` variable, it is unnecessary.

Comment: I see what you are saying, with regards to a lot of the vue documentation on their site, but even within this article (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) there are some that have it (and use it) and at least one version that does not.  So the cases in the documentation that have it and do not demonstrate a usage of it, are probably just the personal coding practice of the dev(s) that made those articles.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have seen everyone storing the Vue instance in an app constant and never referenced them again. I know it's unnecessary. 
Then again I was looking for use cases if they have any. Otherwise, why are they even in vuejs documentation.

Comment: Ok, so with relation to "looking for use cases if they have any", that article has some

Comment: Thanks Taplar for your comment. But, I have read that documentation. I think in that document the `vm` variable was used to clarify how Vue instance works. 
But I don't find any real usage which is where my question lies. Why in every tutorial and project that I have seen declared that way? In there any real usage?

Comment: So, to try to keep this within the confines of StackOverflow, you may want to provide a definition by which you consider something to be a "real usage".  I assume I know what you are after, a real world example.  However, within the context of S.O. that's not a coding problem.  That's just asking for examples.  Which is quasi asking for off site resources, and also quasi too broad, when left in that form.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case.

One reason could be that you're having an already deployed app in production. You may want to only add Vue.js to some parts of the app. You may even have multiple vue instances on the same page, so saving a reference to them makes sense.

Another reason is to use a global event bus. When implementing this you'll save a reference to a new Vue component. Similar to this:

`Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue();`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It makes sense. But how saving vue instance in variable helps while having multiple Vue instances on the same page. Because Vue instances are loaded base on the `el` property.
I am actually working on a project where there are multiple Vue instances. So a little clarification will help.

Comment: This depends heavily on your use case. One reason I can think of is emitting a message to all instances. For this, you'd need to have a ref to all of them to run emit on each one.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a use case. And I think it clarifies my question as well.

Note that we can't use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. 
Since an arrow function doesn’t have a `this`, `this` will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.`

But, if we use an arrow function with the data property, this won’t be the component’s instance, but we can still access the instance as the function’s first argument:

```
var data = { a: 1 }

// direct instance creation
var vm = new Vue({
  data: data
})
vm.a // => 1
vm.$data === data // => true

// must use function when in Vue.extend()
var Component = Vue.extend({
  data: vm => ({ a: vm.myProp })
})
```

But this is not the common practice. We usually declare data property in components as functions so that we can directly access the vue instance.

```
// must use function when in Vue.extend()
var Component = Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return { a: 1 }
  }
})
```